# Reading lotus notes documents using c#

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

Please check the below  code...is this correct one to read the lotus notes documents(.nsf) files......And i got the console message as "connected"(connected to the server).....

How can I access the items of each document? For example I want subject, who, date, time,...

How can I iterate throug all items of a document?

How can I extract attachments?

Moreover how would i know "is it reads the documents or not"
what is meaning of reading documents...and after that..we need to export/migrate to sharepoint. Thats is the main bottom line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Domino;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creating the notes session and passing password
            NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
            session.Initialize("Sep@2011");
            NotesDatabase NotesDb = session.GetDatabase("vm-domino6", "mts.nsf", false);

            if (NotesDb == null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Can not connect to server.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }

            Domino.NotesDocumentCollection col = NotesDb.AllDocuments;
            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; ++i)
            {
                Domino.NotesDocument doc = col.GetNthDocument(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is **too broad** - split it into two separate questions: (1) reading the Lotus Notes documents, (2) importing documents into SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

To read all collection documents try:

```
var document = col.GetFirstDocument();
while (document != null )
{
    document = col.GetNextDocument(document);
}
```